# RazorPage binding not working as expected

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have the following HTML:

```
<label asp-for="CurrentLocation.Description" class="text-info"></label>
```

And in the bound model:

```
public class NavigationModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        CurrentLocation = new Location()
        {
            Description = "test"
        };
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Location CurrentLocation { get; set; }
}
```

So, to my understanding of RazorPages, the site should display "test"; but instead, it displays "Description".  I've looked at several examples where this sort of thing works fine, and I can't see why my version might be different.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro), what you observe is the correct value: `Description`.

> The asp-for attribute is made available by the For property in the `LabelTagHelper`. See [Authoring Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring) for more information.

Labels, in Razor parlance, have never displayed the value of a property, but rather the name if it.

To display the value use something like

```
<label asp-for="CurrentLocation.Description" for="theValue" class="text-info">
</label>
<span id="theValue"> @model.CurrentLocation.Description</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The label tag will just display the name of the property you use.

If you want to display an input with the contents of the Description property then you will have to type the followign code:

```
<input asp-for="CurrentLocation.Description" type="hidden" />
```

if you want to display the value of the property as a label then you will have to type the following:

```
@CurrentLocation.Description
```